# How to insert/add Space between number in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want to add space between numbers

`val value : Long = 8_000_000L
println(value)`

to become this output `8 000 000`

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Comment: val value : Long = 8_000_000L
println(value)

but I want to the output has a space between the number

Comment: Worth pointing out for the record that the Kotlin constant `8_000_000L` means exactly the same as `8000000L`; the underscores are ignored by the compiler.  (So if you put spaces in later, there's no guarantee they'll be in the same places as the underscores.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DecimalFormat` plus some postprocessing (replace comma with space)

```
DecimalFormat("###,###").format(8_000_000L).replace(',', ' ')
```

Edit:

You can also specify grouping symbol explicitly

```
val value = DecimalFormat("###,###", DecimalFormatSymbols().apply {
    groupingSeparator = ' '
}).format(8_000_000L)
println(value)
```

Comment: warning: not all Locales have `,` as thousands separator

Comment: @laalto thanks for the input. Would specifying the grouping symbol work for all Locales?